# Store an integer in a custom object with powershell

Tags: powershell, object, types

I like to use constructs like the following in powershell.  They make following what is happening 6 months later a lot easier.

```
$processConfig = New-Object -TypeName psobject
$processConfig | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name StartDate -Value ($startofweek)
$processConfig | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name StartDateStr -Value (Get-Date $processConfig.StartDate -Format "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss")
$processConfig | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name EndDate -Value ($endofweek)
$processConfig | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name EndDateStr -Value (Get-Date     $processConfig.EndDate -Format "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss")
$processConfig | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name TargetDir -Value  "C:\Scripts\out\"

$dbConfig = New-Object -TypeName psobject
$dbConfig | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Server -Value "server.address"
#etc
```

However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to store a plain int as a property.  I've tried a few different things.

Requires a MemberType

```
$processConfig | Add-Member -TypeName System.Int32 -Name TrimLeadingLines -Value 3
```

Then why is Property a suggested value for the argument?

```
$processConfig | Add-Member -MemberType Property -TypeName System.Int32 -Name TrimLeadingLines -Value 3

Add-Member : Cannot add a member with type "Property". Specify a different type for the MemberTypes parameter.
At C:\Scripts\kh_tca_export_ftps.ps1:80 char:18
+ ... essConfig | Add-Member -MemberType Property -TypeName System.Int32 -N ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Add-Member], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotAddMemberType,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddMemberCommand
```

Thinking sideways, but a bit dodgy

```
$processConfig | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -TypeName System.Int32 -Name TrimLeadingLines -Value { return 3 }
```

I do *not* want to store a string representation I then need to cast.  Yes i can use a $var.   Is there a simple straightforward way to store an Integer/Int32 in Powershell Custom Object?

Comment: As for readability: The PSv3+ `[pscustomobject] @ { StartDate = ...; ... }` syntax is arguably more readable and definitely more efficient than multiple `Add-Member` calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have always done `[int]3` as per below. Works well when I need to store an int in an object.

```
$processConfig | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name TrimLeadingLines -Value $([int]3)
```

This returns an `Int32` as the property type.

```
PS C:\> $processConfig.TrimLeadingLines.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name  BaseType        
-------- -------- ----  --------        
True     True     Int32 System.ValueType
```

Comment: just a comment - my GetType() is much longer, and reads like a key/pair list, niot a table.  What version are you running?

Comment: @Hecatonchires PSVersion is 5.1.17763.592

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr**

`-Value 3` *implicitly* creates an `[int]` property - no extra effort required:

```
$processConfig | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name TrimLeadingLines -Value 3
```

---

- **Whatever data type the `-Value` argument has becomes the new property's data type**.

  - A numeric literal such as `3`, which fits into the `[int]` (`System.Int32`) type's range, is implicitly `[int]` typed, so no further action is needed for creating an `[int]`-typed `NoteProperty`.
  - **To coerce to a different type, use an *expression* with a *cast*; e.g., `-Value ([long] 3)`**
- **The `-TypeName` argument does *not* control a newly added property's data type**; instead, it **assigns an - arbitrary, self-chosen - *type name* to the input object**, as reflected in the object's `.pstypenames` array afterwards (as the *first* element) and as also reflected when you pipe the object to `Get-Member` afterwards.

  - Such self-assigned type names are part of PowerShell's ETS (Extended Type System) - see [about_Types.ps1xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_types.ps1xml)

---

> why is `Property` a suggested value for the [`-MemberType`] argument?

The data type of the mandatory `-MemberType` parameter is [`[System.Management.Automation.PSMemberTypes]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psmembertypes), an enumeration type that is used not *just* by `Add-Member`, but also by other cmdlets, such as `Get-Member`, where *preexisting* members are targeted by type.

- **In the context of `Add-Member`'s `-MemberType` parameter, enumeration value `Property` is not a valid option**, because it refers to a .NET type's innate properties, and those cannot be added to.
- **With `Add-Member` you can only *decorate* existing .NET type instances, and are therefore limited to a *subset* of the enumeration values in `[System.Management.Automation.PSMemberTypes]`**. 
  Notable ones are:

  - `NoteProperty` (property with static value)
  - `ScriptProperty` (a calculated property whose value is determined by a script block's output)
  - `ScriptMethod` (a method whose return value is determined by a script block's output)
  - `CodeProperty` / `CodeMethod` (a property / method whose (return) value is determined by a .NET type's static method).

Tab completion for `Add-Member`'s `-MemberType` parameter has no way of knowing what particular subset of the `[System.Management.Automation.PSMemberTypes]`enumeration values `Add-Member`  is restricted to, because that information isn't in the parameter declaration; however, [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Add-Member#parameters) does list the subset explicitly.